# Use types (interfaces) from other commonjs modules in Visual Studio using TypeScript without having to import that module?

Tags: visual-studio, import, module, typescript, commonjs

I'm trying to simply use types (interfaces) from other commonjs modules. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without having to import the module each time I need just the types (no implementation)?

Also to the same point. How would I use commonjs declared module types in projects without compiling with "--module commonjs"? (just to use the types, I'm aware you could do `var x = require('x')` if you don't care about type safety, but that defeats the purpose of TypeScript)

This seems like a valid use case as one could desire to create a library free from the actual implementation... But as I currently see it, you have to `import x = require('x')` on the actual implementation, even if I don't need it and already have the definition file.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that it "just exists," similar to how declare works with variables?

Example:

Suppose I have file.ts that I'm not compiling with any module setting (none):

```
/// <reference path="ExternalCommonJSModule.d.ts" />

export class A {

   public foo(bar: ITypeFromExternalCommonJSModule): number {
        return bar.x * 2;
   }

}
```

And suppose ExternalCommonJSModule.d.ts looks like this:

```
declare module "ExternalCommonJSModule" {

     export interface ITypeFromExternalCommonJSModule {
          x: number;
     }

}
```

(note, this **doesn't** compile because file.ts isn't compiled with --module commonjs and it doesn't import the implementation of the .d.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without having to import the module each time I need just the types (no implementation)

You can put the interfaces in a global module e.g. `globals.d.ts` and then you would be able to use them throughout the project without importing.

Note: as soon as you global you are severely limiting the *shareability* of your code and opening yourself to the *diamond version dependency problem*.

Comment: As your gitbook says, it's sometimes useful to have globally available types. The project which uses the global types isn't meant to be used externally, but rather is a very specific server implementation. Thanks.

Comment: How does typescript find the `globals.d.ts` module? Does the name matter in some way?